# Missing TXT file in a PHP form. Any idea what it should contain?

Tags: php, txt, formmail

I have this code on a php mail form that used to work until recently.

```
//Open last-order.txt file for getting the order number
    $readFile = fopen("./order.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $orden= fread($readFile,filesize("./order.txt"));
    fclose($readFile);
    ++$orden;
    $writeFile= fopen("./order.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($writeFile, $orden);
    fclose($writeFile);
            
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $website)) $website = "http://" . $website;
    
    $website = filter_var($website, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $participantes = filter_var($_POST["participantes"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

It references a TXT file named order.txt that read the file and increases the number by one each time is read. Unfortunately, I lost this file when the hosting provider left me in the cold with the service, with no way to access the server or its backup.

This is the text that I put on the TXT file:

```
Orden: 8000
```

I am not really a proficient PHP coder, so my attempts to recreate it or make it work, have been fruitless.

This is the error am getting:

```
[03-Jan-2023 13:29:22 America/Mexico_City] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $email_content in /home/guillerm/iefa.com.mx/rsvp/php/reserve.php on line 78
[03-Jan-2023 13:29:22 America/Mexico_City] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/guillerm/iefa.com.mx/rsvp/php/reserve.php:78) in /home/guillerm/iefa.com.mx/rsvp/php/reserve.php on line 149
```

Any help pointing me to the right direction, will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: just put the number in the text file (remove `Orden: `), the error about `$email_content` may or may not get fixed as your not showing that part of the code

Comment: Thanks, that is working now. The code that is prompting the error is this ` Returns in the Gframe ajax format.
 Input: data array processed by constructAjaxResponseArray ()
 Outputs as a html stream then exits.
*/
function returnAndExitAjaxResponse ($_ajaxResponse) {
 if(!$_ajaxResponse){
  $_ajaxResponse = array('response'=>false,'message'=>'Unknown error occurred.');
 }
 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
 echo json_encode($_ajaxResponse);
 die();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's literally just supposed to be a number. replace `Orden: 8000` with just `8000`.

btw that code is [thread-unsafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) and the number may collide/duplicate if you run multiple instances of the code at the same time; if thread-safety is desired, you can instead do

```
$readFile = fopen("./order.txt", "c+b") or die("Unable to open file!");
flock($readFile, LOCK_EX);
$orden = (int)stream_get_contents($readFile);
++$orden;
rewind($readFile);
fwrite($readFile, (string) $orden);
flock($readFile, LOCK_UN);
fclose($readFile);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is quite helpful!